# How to make Toyota Prius resume playback where it stopped?

Tags: music-player, bluetooth-audio

I have a 2019 Toyota Prius that can play music from my Android phone using Bluetooth. On my phone I am using Musicolet as the music player.

Some of the time, this works perfectly: the music plays in the order I chose on the phone, and if I shut down the car and then restart it, the music restarts where it left off.

However, other times the following happens when I tell the car to use the Bluetooth source. The screen comes up, asking me to choose which app to use. I only have one choice, which is Musicolet, so I choose that. Then it asks me whether to resume playback, or shuffle all the songs in the playlist. I choose to resume.

I think this bad behaviour started in the last few months, and since the car hasn't had any software updates, it's possibly an Android or Musicolet update that caused it.

Does anyone know an Android or Musicolet (or maybe Toyota Prius) configuration change that will make the bad behaviour go away?

Comment: I find this normal for many apps, including Android Auto running a navigation app.  Sometimes it resumes, other times it doesn't.

Comment: @RohitGupta:  That's discouraging.  Maybe there's a workaround, e.g. a way to modify some config file on the phone to tell the car there aren't any choices, just start right now.